# Load Database in core file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a `core` file in `codeigniter` for user and want to run some database queries there as well. core file is for `users` so when ever i open website users data hould be available automatically and no need to create a library and call it again and again.

I have tried autoloader and Codeigniter.php file but its not working.Do anyone have idea how to achive this. so that i can use 'user' function easily like. `$this->user->login()` , `$this->user->logout()` ... same as some builtin functions pre-loaded like `$this->input->get()` or `$this->load->SOMETHING()`... etc etc.

Comment: Just load the auth library in MY_Controller in core and use parent::__construct(); in your Controllers constructor which extends MY_Controller

Answer (score 0):

You can try hooks for db in core file. enable hooks on config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

and use this for more see this https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/hooks.html

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$this->CI->db->select('*')
```

Comment: Not working ... gives error at line 332 in Codeigniter.php core file.. (Controller not found)